# Error C# (CS0246) while implementing an interface in a class in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, parametric-polymorphism

I'm getting acquainted with the Polymorphism of OOP while making a game in Unity.

I try to use an interface that will take part in a damage system.

Here is the interface code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public interface IDamageable 
{
    int Health { get; set;}
    void Damage();
}
```

And here is the code of a skeleton enemy, who inherits from the parent class `Enemy` and has to implement the `IDamageable` interface:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Skeleton : Enemy, IDamageable
{
    public int Health { get; set; }

    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();
        Health = base.health;
    }

    public void Damage()
    {
    }
}
```

So the thing is that the console in Unity doesn't show any error messages regarding the interface.

But the VS Code keeps the `IDamageable` underlined with an error CS0246:

> The type or namespace name 'IDamageable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Looks like VS Code doesn't even see the interface - can't find the interface in intellisense either.

I tried to implement the interface for some other enemies, but the case is the same: no error in the unity console, and the interface is also marked by VS Code.

Sorry if that question is dumb!

Comment: Those classes should live in namespaces.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield while good practice. It should be fine within unity without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it took time, but I found a solution to this issue.

The thing is that a namespace is not a necessity in this case.
I did read about namespaces but am not sure how to use them yet. And the course I follow doesn't use namespaces either.

So about the issue.
Due to the appearance of the error - it appears only in VS Code, I decided to do the following:

1. While in **Unity** entered **Preferences -> External tools**
2. Saw that in the field **External Script Editor** I had **Open by file extension**
3. Changed that field to **Visual Studio Code**
4. Pressed **Regenerate project files**

The error CS0246 in VS Code disappeared, and the interface was implemented successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recompile the script, see what's up. If issue persists delete script, write it again. Most likely there is some BS with assembly

Comment: I tried to recompile the script and rewrite it. The issue persists. Sorry what is a "BS"?

Comment: Search it yourself. Anyway,the issue is clear compiler doesn't know about your script 's existence. Best solution is to delete script,relaunch unity, create new script with different name.  I don't know more